# How many degrees of freedom R package: 'fGarch'

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to know how to find out the number of degrees of freedom for a t-student distribution of standardized residuals of a GARCH model (using garchFit on R from the fGarch package).

Is there an other package or any other way to estimate this parameter?

Comment: This seems like it would be better suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), the SE site for statistics. Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

garchFit uses 4 degrees of freedom by default, specified in the `shape` parameter, so I'd say if you didn't set it to be estimated with `include.shape=TRUE`, the degrees of freedom are the default, fixed at 4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While fitting with garchfit option `include.shape=TRUE` we get a shape of 3.72, however, the final qqpot (testing several values for nu) shows that the residuals follows a t-student distribution with approximately 10 degrees of freedom. Does the `shape` parameter returned by garchfit corresponds to the optimal dfs ??? thanks.

Comment: In general, yes, the `shape` parameter is equal to the degrees of freedom, as the t-distribution's shape is determined by its degrees of freedom. I'm  not sure why you're getting a different reading from the residual plot...

Comment: the problem is solved, I was doing the wrong qqplots... Thank you very much for your help!